# Why is my second greendao insert not working?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, greendao, android-database

I am using greendao for an application of mine. I used a generator to create all of the tables and I am running test right now. The insert is working for the user table, but not for the group table. There's little different between the two entity models, so I don't know why I'm getting an insert error.

Here are all of my models

```
private static void addMessage() {
    Entity message = schema.addEntity("Message");
    message.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
    message.addStringProperty("mtext").notNull();
    message.addDateProperty("date").getProperty();
    message.addLongProperty("userId").notNull();
    message.addLongProperty("groupId").notNull();

}

private static void addUser(){
    Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
    user.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
    user.addStringProperty("username").notNull().unique();
    user.addStringProperty("email").notNull().unique();
    // Not necessary if group does not exist
    user.addStringProperty("token").unique(); // Doesn't have to be there unique
}

private static void addGroup(){
    Entity group = schema.addEntity("Group");
    group.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
    group.addStringProperty("name").notNull();
    group.addStringProperty("description").notNull();
}

private static void addUserToGroup(){
    Entity ugSchema = schema.addEntity("UserGroup");
    ugSchema.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
    ugSchema.addLongProperty("userId").notNull();
    ugSchema.addLongProperty("groupId").notNull();
}
```

Here's my test method. Keep in mind that I use statics to control the DAO sessions. If you think that might contribute to something tell me.

```
public void testDB(){

    User inUser = new User();
    inUser.setEmail("KevinKivo@gmail.com");
    inUser.setUsername("KevinKivo");
    inUser.setToken("TheRandomTokenGoesHere");
    Database.getuser().insert(inUser);
    ArrayList<User> user = (ArrayList<User>)
            Database.getuser()
                    .queryBuilder()
                    .list();
    // Can create message and
    for(User us: user){
        Log.i(TAG, "Email: " + us.getEmail());
        Log.i(TAG, "Username: " + us.getUsername());
        Log.i(TAG, "Token: " + us.getToken());
    }

    // Create a group here
    Group sampleGroup = new Group();
    sampleGroup.setName("SampleName");
    sampleGroup.setDescription("SampleDescription");

    Log.i(TAG, "" + Database.getGroup());
    Log.i(TAG, "" + Database.getuser());
    Log.i(TAG, "" + Database.getGroup().insertOrReplace(sampleGroup));


    // Add user and group id relation here
}
```

Inserting the user works perfectly while inserting a group does not. Could somebody explain why? This issue is plaguing my life right now. I'm working on other parts of the application, but this is seriously important.

Comment: I'm a little shocked by how are you inserting the objects in the DB. I've been using greenDao for a while and I always use DaoMaster and DaoSession to insert elements. How is that? Do you have som intermediate controller or something like that?

Comment: I was using a Group and User daos. It's all good now. I realize that it was only the naming convention.

Comment: Actually, are you not using the DAO Generator to generate the DAOs and Objects? Why you should renaming them?